# Transform JSON array using ES 6 methods

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I have the following example of an array format that needs to be transformed.

```
{ [
  {
    "condition": "$and",
    "children": [
      { "column": "Title", "comparison": "$eq", "columnValue": "1" },
      { "column": "Event Status", "comparison": "$eq", "columnValue": "2" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "condition": "$or",
    "children": [
      {
        "column": "Issue Description",
        "comparison": "$lt",
        "columnValue": "3"
      },
      { "column": "Number Label", "comparison": "$gte", "columnValue": "4" }
    ]
  }
]}
```

It needs to be transformed like this...

```
{ 
    [
        { 
            "$and" : [
                { 
                    "Title" : {
                        "$eq" : "1"
                    }
                }, 
                { 
                    "Event Status" : {
                        "$eq" : "2"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }, 
        { 
            "$or" : [
                { 
                    "Issue Description" : { 
                        "$lt" : "3"
                    }
                }, 
                { 
                    "Number Label" : { 
                        "$gte" : "4"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried various iterations of map and reduce.  Gotten close, but not completely there.

This is in a Vue project.  Here is an example of what I tried.

```
const result = this.parents.map(({ condition, children }) => {
        const childArray = children.reduce(
          (c, v) => ({
            ...c,
            [v.column]: { [v.comparison]: v.columnValue }
          }),
          {}
        );
        childArray.condition = condition;
        return childArray;
      });
```

This returns:

```
[
  {
    "Title": { "$eq": "1" },
    "Event Status": { "$eq": "2" },
    "condition": "$and"
  },
  {
    "Issue Description": { "$lt": "3" },
    "Number Label": { "$gte": "4" },
    "condition": "$or"
  }
]
```

I cannot figure out how to get the "condition" key in the right place.

Comment: If you tried different things please include them so people can spot where you might went wrong and help you better instead of thinking others will write the code for me

Comment: Do it in two steps.  It would be pretty easy to map through each of those to pull out the condition.

Comment: your JSON origin is invalid -> `{ [`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ES6 computed property names will be a big help, allowing variable expression enclosed in `[]` square braces to compute a key value...

```js
let inputExpressions = [
  {
    "condition": "$and",
    "children": [
      { "column": "Title", "comparison": "$eq", "columnValue": "1" },
      { "column": "Event Status", "comparison": "$eq", "columnValue": "2" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "condition": "$or",
    "children": [
      {
        "column": "Issue Description",
        "comparison": "$lt",
        "columnValue": "3"
      },
      { "column": "Number Label", "comparison": "$gte", "columnValue": "4" }
    ]
  }
];

function translateExpression(expression) {
  const translateClause = clause => {
    return { [clause.column] :  { [clause.comparison] : clause.columnValue } };
  };
  return { [expression.condition] : expression.children.map(translateClause) };
}

let resultExpressions = inputExpressions.map(translateExpression);
console.log(resultExpressions)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Exactly what I was trying to understand.  Appreciate the answer..